# How do I decrease the saltiness in pork meatballs?

Tags: seasoning

If I simmer salty pork meatballs in low sodium tomato juice or sauce would it decrease the saltiness in the meatball?

Comment: How did they get salt in them in the first place? If you are buying mince that is already salty talk to your butcher. If your buying pre-prepared meatballs that are too salty, switch brands or make them yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make the taste of the meatball less salty is to make the tomato sauce a bit sweeter than you normally want it.

Another option is to make the sauce a bit spicy. Both sweetness and spiciness will lower your tongue's perception of saltiness.

Note that it will not make the meatballs noticeably less salty themselves. This only hides the saltiness, so if you are trying to lower the sodium due to dietary restrictions, this will not help in that regard.

If the meatball is so salty that the sweet/spicy sauce doesn't mask it, you can re-purpose the meatball in other ways. Some ideas include:

- Break them up into little pieces and sprinkle on top of a salad (treat it like how some people treat bacon bits in a salad).
- Try eating the meatballs in a sandwich with the sweet/spicy tomato sauce. Sandwich bread is very neutral in taste and can help with the saltiness.
- Break into bits and add into a baked pasta dish.
- Add it into a vegetable or noodle soup.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all, the poster is asking whether cooking meatballs in a sauce will reduce the salt content.

Comment: @GdD : not necessarily.  They ask about 'saltiness' which might be salt content, or perceived salt level (which this answer could help)

Comment: @GdD because of the duality of the meaning, I even made a note that my methods doesn't physically lower the salt content, only the perception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cooking a salty meatball in a low sodium sauce will reduce the saltiness a bit as some of the salt will be cooked out, however the effect won't be that much. If you want to try it keep in mind that canned tomatoes have a fair amount of salt added (it helps preserve them), so you'd be best off making a fresh tomato sauce.

Answer (score 0):

You can soak them in water for awhile then rinse out some of it out. Can do two three times. Or boil it out however this might make them tougher.